# Navbar menus not showing in mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a resposive site which works fine on desktop but not in mobile and Tablet view. Menus in navbar are not showing in Mobile and Tablet View

You can check the link here for screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/866bi2l7oho5w6y/prob1.JPG

This is my website: http://www.sociolife.co.in/

PS: Navbars are shown in Tablet and Mobile view but the menus are not shown.

Can you please tell me where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please supply code to a specific problem. Your issue is too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a `media-query` which sets the `#menu-main` to `display: none` in smaller windows than `1024px`

remove this line form your css and everything works fine:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1028px)
#menu-main {
  display: none;
}
```

**//EDIT** no u didn't remove it, otherwise it would look like this: 
http://imgur.com/XX2SlfG

**//EDIT 2** ok now i get it. They have a second navigation implemented which is a selectbox. That's why tey hide the `#menu-main` in mobile and show the `#tinynav1`. maybe you should add this link into your questions, otherwise no one knows what you want to achieve.

The selecbox looks like this:

```
<select id="tinynav1" class="tinynav tinynav1">
    <option>Navigation</option>
    <option>your options</option>
    ....
</select>
```

But i guess this is a JS plugin from their page, i don't know if you have this plugin. otherwise please google it:

```
 $("#menu-main").tinyNav({
    active: 'selected', // String: Set the "active" class
    header: 'Navigation', // String: Specify text for "header" and show header instead of the active item
    label: '' 
});
```

http://tinynav.viljamis.com/ <-- js library

Comment: i will remove this whole code? @media only screen and (max-width: 1028px)
#menu-main {
  display: none;
}

Comment: yea at least the part `#menu-main {display: none}` since i don't know if you got further code inside the media query

Comment: i removed that part but it did not fix. the template which i am using that is working fine.  here is screenshot of tthe template which I am using: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/e1ard35770w0rx6/prob2.JPG

Comment: bro i removed it now but its not fixing it. the navbar part is moving away towards right

Comment: so what should it look like. it is showing the menu right now on your live page in mobile.

Comment: it should look like this: http://dynamicmag-sbtemplates.blogspot.in/ the sample template which I am using. please check the sample site in mobile view.... You will get it what I am trying to say

Comment: bro i am having tinynav js pugin and i m using the above snippet also. still its not working. can u please check out what is the problem